# How to Deploy MS Botframework in Python to Azure

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot

I've been playing with Botframework and am trying to upload the sample code from the git https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python/tree/master/samples/EchoBot-with-State (with minor modifications) to Azure cloud. I've been referring to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-deploy-azure?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

but have not been able to do so. Looks like this guide is more for .NET / .JS based applications and I'm not sure how to use Visual Studio with Python code to deploy to Azure.

I've never used Visual Studio before and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge BOT is app service hosted on Azure. So to publish your bot application you will need to follow the same steps involved in publishing Python web app to Azure.
You can follow steps in below link.

[Publishing Python web app to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use github to deploy a Python WebApp

Go to web app in Azure -> Deployment Center -> Connect Github account -> choose Org/Repo/Branch

[image]

[image]