# Azure Deployment Issue in Python Language using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: python, azure, deployment, botframework, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy a bot to Azure built on Microsoft Bot Framework in Python. The Bot is working locally on Bot Emulator. Using Visual Studio Code for the bot development.

Deployed the Bot to Azure on a WebApp successfully using the startup command as :

```
python3.7 -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:init_func
```

My app.py file:

```
def init_func(argv):
    app = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
    app.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
    return app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = init_func(None)

    try:
        web.run_app(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=CONFIG.PORT)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error
```

**The Error I am getting is **

> 2021-06-07T14:15:21.045987180Z aiohttp.web: error: unable to import main: No module named 'app'

I referred following answers from stackoverflow, but it doesn't work for me

1. [How to Deploy MS Botframework in Python to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484875/how-to-deploy-ms-botframework-in-python-to-azure)
2. [Running an Python App as an Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507967/running-an-python-app-as-an-azure-web-app)

Also referred the Microsoft documentation:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-flask
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-language-python
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#modulenotfounderror-when-app-starts
4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-04

I am stuck in deploying this bot to Azure for a week now. Any help/pointers/suggestions is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you checked here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w7UT_wx-tk

Comment: Yes i did. Yours was the first video that I referred. But, its not working for me. I followed your video step-by-step instead of uploading the code through GitHub, I am using VSCode extension for Azure App Service.

Comment: I tried your EchoBot code from the link - https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/BotTutorialSample/tree/master/Python_tutorial/22-aihttp_azure/EchoBot            
And it worked in emulator and following the same steps when I deployed it to webapp it is giving me error -
1. Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app'. startup - gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app:appstartup - gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app:init_func()
2. TypeError: init_func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given 
3. TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: Are you really using `python3.7` as a command rather than `python` or `py` or `py -3.7`? I've never seen that before. You say you're using VS Code for deployment but the documentation you linked to doesn't mention VS Code. How are you using that documentation? One of the documents you linked to clearly explains that the error you're seeing is most likely caused by erroneously deploying a virtual environment. Have you verified that you're not deploying a virtual environment by checking the code in your app service? Please be more descriptive about what's happening than saying "it's not working"

Comment: I have a similar problem - trying to deploy a simple bot written in c# (with MS Bot Framework) into a Linux-based App Service. So far no luck. Can't even find if its possible

Comment: @Ruchita Harsora -  I tried deployment again & it’s working fine . Seems to your deployment process has some problem (your code is not deployed) , move the sample code in GitHub and try again.

Comment: @KyleDelaney - I was using python3.7 as the startup command as mentioned in one of the stackoverflow accepted answers. I used VS Code for building the chatbot in Python and deployed it to Azure using the Azure App Service extension. But it did not work for me. So I pushed my code to GitHub and then deployed to WebApp. I am using this start up command - `gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app:init_func` and this is the error I am getting in LogStream : TypeError: init_func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some restrictions to create app id and password in your student azure account, try to check without app id and password

hope it will work.

Comment: This worked for me using ngrok. Thank you Vinoth Rajendran for all the help.